# How to combine two columns from rows?

Tags: sql-server

How to combine two columns from one row of a table?

Talbe

| ID | RulesID | ObjectID | TypeID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 56 | 1 |
| 7 | 9 | 43 | 3 |
| 24 | 9 | 73 | 2 |
| 31 | 9 | 94 | 3 |
| 33 | 9 | 20 | 4 |
| 45 | 9 | 1008 | 8 |
| 46 | 9 | 1009 | 7 |

Result

| RulesID | ObjectID | TypeID | ObjectID2 | TypeID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 56 | 1 | 43 | 3 |
| 9 | 73 | 2 | 94 | 3 |
| 9 | 20 | 4 | 1008 | 8 |
| 9 | 1009 | 7 | null | null |

Comment: What is the rule behind the desired result? Why not 43 and 73 in the same row?

Comment: You can Use Pivot, this is was posted years ago
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: @MartinSmith, I want to combine odd and even rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using row_number() and the modulus to determine column. Then it becomes a small matter for a conditional aggregegation.

**Example**

```
Select RulesID
      ,ObjectID  = max( case when Col=1 then ObjectID end)
      ,TypeID    = max( case when Col=1 then TypeID end)
      ,ObjectID2 = max( case when Col=0 then ObjectID end)
      ,TypeID2   = max( case when Col=0 then TypeID end)
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = (1+row_number() over (partition by RulesID order by ID)) / 2
              ,Col = row_number() over (partition by RulesID order by ID) % 2
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Group By RulesID,Grp
```

**Results**

[image]